# script to split a string google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help please here with a script for google sheet. I got a zapier which take some information from a system and paste it on my google, The problem is that the system send the info as a string with comas like that one : andres,locuara@gmail.com,Albania,creation loca,holatu@gmail.com

So I was using the formula SPLIT on google sheet and that formula works fine but the problem is that everytime when zapier send the information to the sheet I dont know what happened but zapier delete the formular from the sheet so I need to go manualy and do the formula again to to split the info and put where it needs to be. So I would like to make an script which cannot be deleted and do all the job as It needs to be on the whole sheet.

I got that structure like this:

[image]

and I would like that the script does the job in every cell automatically in the whole sheet. Please is there someone who can help me out with that . ? Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

It will add an item to your command tab bar in Google Sheet when you open the Sheet. Then you just press run and wait.

```
function onOpen() { 
  // Try New Google Sheets method
  try{
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Split cells')
    .addItem('Run', 'main')
    .addToUi(); 
  }

  // Log the error
  catch (e){Logger.log(e)}

}


function main() {

  var settings = {
    dataCol: 3,
    nameCol: 4,
    /*
    mailCol: 5,
    teamCol: 6,
    teamNameCol: 7,
    contactCol: 8, 
    spreadsheet: {}
    */

  }

  settings.dataCol--;
  settings.nameCol--;
  /*
  settings.mailCol--;
  settings.teamCol--;
  settings.teamNameCol--;
  settings.contactCol--; 
  */

  settings.spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < settings.spreadsheet.length; i++) {
    var arr = settings.spreadsheet[i][settings.dataCol].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; i++) {
      settings.spreadsheet[i][settings.nameCol + j] = arr[j] ;
    }

  }



  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().setValues(settings.spreadsheet);

}
```

Comment: Hello that function ask me to give all the right to see all my google sheet in that account. is It that normal ?

Comment: @George Add this somewhere in the code `//@OnlyCurrentDoc`

Comment: It doesn't work my friend... the thing is like this :
1.- I got a system which I can register people
2.- Zapier takes all these info and make a new register on google sheet
3.- The google sheet needs to have an script to split that information without me - automatically
4.- I got another system which takes these details and do some actions. 

My problem is the split thing that is driving me crazy. =)

Comment: @George So what does it say? What error, output? Did you press "Run" button from your Quick Access Toolbar right next to "Help"?
The script can also be scheduled to run hourly or daily automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try arrayformula:

D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(C2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C)),","))
```

Comment: Hello Thanks a lot for you help. I got an error here =

function myFunction() {
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(C2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C)),","))
}

When I put that I got that error : Error de sintaxis (línea 2, archivo "Código")

Comment: @George It's NOT a script. Just a formula to be entered in D2

Comment: The thing is - if i put a formula like this, when zapier make a new register - zapier will delete that formula and that won't work. That' why I need a script =)

Comment: @George It's a array formula.. As long as D2 is untouched, it won't matter,if zapier deletes  current row like D5 or something...

Comment: I tried again and the thing is the zapier makes a new row so the one that has the formula does't do anything because zapier made another row.

Comment: @Geo Formula is in D2 and it's a array formula. It'll automatically  overflow when a new row is created.